# Weak Convergence of Probability Measures (Proving integrals converge if measures do)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Note: I am doing this question just for fun, not for hw.

**Question: Fix any dense subset $G$ of the unit ball of $C^{0}(M)$. Here $C^0(M)$ refers to the space of continuous functions defined on $M$, a metric space. Show that a sequence of probability measures $(P_n)_n$ on M converges to to some P  $ \in M_1(M)$ in the weak* topology if and only if $\int  \phi d P_n$ converges to $\int \phi d P$ for every $\phi \in G$.**

Note: here, $M_1(M)$ refers to the set of Borel probability measures on M.

Here is the proof of a similar but different question.
A sequence of probability measures $(P_n)_n$ on M converges to to some P  $ \in M_1(M)$ in the weak* topology if and only if $\int  \phi d P_n$ converges to $\int \phi d P$ for every bounded continuous function $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Proof of this question: 
First, a quick definition of the weak* topology. Given a measure $P \in M_1(M)$, a finite set $\phi=\{\phi_1...\phi_N\}$ of bounded continuous functions $\phi_i: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a number $\epsilon >0$, we define $V(P,\phi, \epsilon)$=$\{\nu \in M_1(M): | \int \phi_i d\nu -\int \phi_i d\mu|< \epsilon \mbox{ for every i }\}$. The family $\{V(P,\phi, \epsilon): \phi, \epsilon\}$ may be taken as a neighborhood of each $P \in M_1(M)$. The weak* topology is defined by these bases of neighborhoods.

Now for one direction of the proof. Consider any set $\phi=\{\omega\}$, where $\omega$ is a single bounded continuous function. Since $(P_n)_n \rightarrow P$, we have that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $P_n \in V(P,\phi,\epsilon)$ for every $n\geq N$. This just means that, $|\int \omega dP_n -\int \omega dP|< \epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. $(\int \omega dP_n)_n$ converges to $\int \omega dP $.

For the converse, assume that $(\int \omega P_n)_n$ converges to $
\int \omega P$ for every bounded continuous function $\omega$. We need to show that given  $\phi=\{\omega_1,..\omega_M\}$ and $\epsilon >0$, we have that there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $P_n \in V(P, \phi, \epsilon)$ for $n \geq N$.
To show this, let: $\phi=\{\omega_1,...\omega_M\}$. Our hypothesis ensures that for every $i$ there exists $N_i$ such that $|\int \omega_i dP_n-\int \omega_i dP| < \epsilon$ for every $n >N_i$. Taking N=max$\{N_1....,N_M\}$, we have that $P_n \in V(P,\phi,\epsilon)$ for every $n>N$. Hence, proved.

Thus, I know how to prove the result for every bounded continuous function $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I, however don't understand how the proof changes when we only consider $\phi \in G$ where G is a dense subset of the unit ball of $C^0(M)$ where $C^0(M)$ is the space of continuous functions defined on M. 
Since I proved the result for all bounded and continuous $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then doesn't the case where $\phi$ is in a dense subset of the unit ball of continuous functions defined on $M$ just a special case of the previous one and just immediately follow. It seems too trivial and I feel as if though I am missing something...
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: hi @KaviRamaMurthy what is the definition of $C^{0}(M)$? I took the definition from the textbook.

Comment: Right but if f is bounded then the integral $\int f dP$ must exist?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I took the definition straight from the textbook of $C^0(M)$, i can post a screenshot from the textbook. note that we are considering $f\in G$ where G is a dense subset of the unit ball of $C^0(M)$. shouldn't then $\int f dP$ exist in this case..

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and I am deleting previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned $P_n$ converges in the weak* topology to $P$ if 
\begin{equation*}
\int f d P_n \to \int f d P
\end{equation*}
for every bounded continuous function $f$ defined on the metric space $M$. We just need to verify this condition.

Fix the bounded continuous function $f$. Without loss of generality we assume $f$ is bounded uniformly by $1$, since otherwise we can replace $f$ by $f / ||f||$, where $||f|| := \sup_{x \in M} |f(x)|$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, pick some $\phi \in G$ that approximates $f$ uniformly on $M$, i.e. $\sup_{x \in M} |f(x) - \phi(x)| < \varepsilon$. We have the estimate
\begin{align*}
\left| \int f d P_n - \int f d P \right| &\leq \left| \int (f-\phi) d P_n \right| + \left| \int \phi d P_n - \int \phi d P \right| + \left| \int (\phi - f) d P \right| \\
&\leq 2 \varepsilon + \left| \int \phi d P_n - \int \phi d P \right|
\end{align*}
Taking limit on both sides yields
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n} \left| \int f d P_n - \int f d P \right| \leq 2\varepsilon
\end{equation*}
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude $\int f d P_n \to \int f d P$.

Comment: I already proved that is true for $f$ bounded continuous that integrals $\int f dP_n \rightarrow \int f DP$ converge. But I need to prove that for $\phi \in G$ that $\int \phi dPn \rightarrow \int \phi dP$.

Comment: hi @YeZ i upvoted your answer but I need to show the integrals converge for $\phi \in G$ Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: It sounds like I got your question wrong. Are you asking how to show weak* convergence of $P_n$ implies convergence of the integrals of $\phi \in G$? But doesn't this follow directly from the definition of weak* convergence (because $\phi$ is bounded continuous function)?

Comment: that's what I'm not sure about, so I wanted to verify with someone. Is $\phi \in G$ where G is dense subset of the unit ball of $C^{0}(M)$ bounded and continuous? Because then doesn't it then just follow from the proof of bounded and continuous that the integrals converge for $\phi \in G$ in the weak*topology as this is just a specific case?

Comment: If $C^0(M)$ is equipped with the supremum norm $||f|| := \sup_{x \in M} |f(x)|$, then any function in the unit ball is bounded by 1. In this case, the convergence just follows from definition of weak* convergence. If this is an exercise, I guess the "only if" part is meant to be trivial and the "if" part is what you should focus on.

Comment: Hi @YeZ I think I was confused earlier. Does your proof show that if $\int \phi dP_n \rightarrow \int \phi dP$ for $\phi \in G$ then $\int f dP_n \rightarrow \int  f dP$? thanks.